# Anyway to Speed up wkhtmltopdf

Tags: c#, html, performance, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to see if there is anyway to make this process faster. The server is 8 CPU cores and 20GB of RAM. I have the timeout set to `70000`. Is it written in a way that only a single core will handle he may be limited by the max speed of the CPU? The server doesn’t seem to be spiked much.

```
public void ExportToPdfInternal(string wkhtmltopdfFileName,
                string printableUrl,
                string printableFooterUrl,
                string printableHeaderUrl,
                string pdfFileName, StringBuilder cookiesStringBuilder,
                bool extendedHeader,
                Action pdfPostProcessingAction)
            {
                string url = printableUrl;
                int timeout = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TemplateExportToPdfTimeout"]);
    
                if (File.Exists(pdfFileName))
                {
                    File.Delete(pdfFileName);
                }
    
                var args = string.Format("--javascript-delay 3000 -q {0} {1} {2} {3} \"{4}\" \"{5}\"",
                    GetPdfMarginParameters(extendedHeader),
                    string.Format(" --footer-html \"{0}\" --header-html \"{1}\" ",
                        printableFooterUrl, printableHeaderUrl),
                    cookiesStringBuilder,
                    null,
                    url,
                    pdfFileName
                    );
    
                int attemps = 0;
                for (attemps = 0; attemps < 5; attemps++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var task = Task.Run(() => ExecuteWkHtmlToPdf(wkhtmltopdfFileName, args));
    
                        if (!task.Wait(timeout))
                        {
                            throw new TimeoutException();
                        }
    
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (TimeoutException tme)
                    {
                        attemps++;
                    }
                }
    
                if (File.Exists(pdfFileName))
                {
                    pdfPostProcessingAction();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Pdf export failed.");
                }
            }
    
            public void ExportToPdf(PdfExportMainParameters parameters)
            {
                ExportToPdfInternal(parameters.WkhtmltopdfFileName,
                    parameters.PrintableUrl,
                    parameters.PrintableFooterUrl,
                    parameters.PrintableHeaderUrl,
                    parameters.PdfFileName,
                    parameters.CookiesStringBuilder,
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.Title) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.CourseTitle),
                    () => PdfPostprocess(parameters.PdfFileName, parameters.PrintedByUserName, parameters.LogoFileName, parameters.GuideLineTitle, parameters.DiseaseTitle, parameters.Title, parameters.TemplateTemplateId, parameters.TemplateLastEditedDate, parameters.FooterHeight));
            }
```

Comment: Given the way wkhtmltopdf works it will _always_ be slow. It's basically creating a customized headless browser and using a version of the "Print as PDF" feature of that browser programmatically. I would reconsider my PDF requirements at this point... if it really is mission critical to do HTML, and you have the budget to experiment; I recommend trying a Node + https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer test. It's less flexible but I hear it's more performant (no 1st hand experience!)

Comment: And yes I do realize puppeteer works in the same way as wkhtmtopdf as a headless browser, BUT I suspect it supports more recent... things (something something patched QT version etc)